# Get pixi.js data by canvas element

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I have a browser extension that needs to pull some information about associated objects drawn at canvas element using PIXI.js.

Some drawing frameworks store associated objects tree using jQuery data() on dom element.
In this case I see it is empty.

PIXI application object is created by an Angular controller and as I can imagine it holds the reference inside.

For example, for this page: https://www.goodboydigital.com/pixijs/examples/13/?base=pixijs&category=examples&post=13 
Is there any helper method or any way I can use something like this:

```
new PIXI.Application(document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0])
```

and get the objects tree?

Comment: What “tree” are you talking about? Canvas is a pixel image format.

Comment: @CBroe, canvas is, but framework to draw it is not. Look at "children" and "graphicsData" properties of the "stage" variable at the given example.

Comment: So what, that doesn’t change the fact that you won’t be able to get any of that by trying to access the canvas element itself, after the data has already been painted. You’d have to interact directly with this framework then somehow.

Comment: @CBroe, yes, that is what I'm asking about. Haven't you seen suggestion to such interaction in the code block? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this page https://www.goodboydigital.com/pixijs/examples/13/?base=pixijs&category=examples&post=13 it is easy to get all objects that you are interested in because they are global - just see source of that page:

```
<body>
    <script>
    

    // create an new instance of a pixi stage
    var stage = new PIXI.Stage(0xFFFFFF, true);
    
    stage.setInteractive(true);
    
    var sprite=  PIXI.Sprite.fromImage("spinObj_02.png");
    //stage.addChild(sprite);
    // create a renderer instance
    //var renderer = new PIXI.CanvasRenderer(800, 600);//PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(800, 600);
    var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(620, 380);
    
    // set the canvas width and height to fill the screen
    //renderer.view.style.width = window.innerWidth + "px";
    //renderer.view.style.height = window.innerHeight + "px";
    renderer.view.style.display = "block";
     
    // add render view to DOM
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.view);

...


        renderer.render(stage);
...
```

You can try using them via developer tools console (in browser like Firefox or Chrome etc);

For example you can open your devtools and run following line in console:

```
graphics.position.x+=10;
```

You should see some objects in canvas moving to right.

Anyway, as i said above: this is the easy case - everything as global variables. When PIXI objects are created inside some other scope (inside some function / class etc) then you will not be able to get them.

About `Application`: As you see there is no `Application` here - the "renderer" is used directly - is what you need to render on canvas. `Application` is just a "helper" object that is not required to work with PIXI - as you my read in its source: https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js/blob/v5.3.7/packages/app/src/Application.ts.

```
/**
 * Convenience class to create a new PIXI application.
 *
 * This class automatically creates the renderer, ticker and root container.
...
```